# Seen the rest of the layout when using the ScrollView in android studio

Tags: android

I have android studio. But when using the `ScrollView` to design the layout and etc in inside the screen, I have a problem and when I want to add the additional tools greater than the screen, I can not do this action.Also I have the  android studio old version.

Comment: What do you meant by additional tools? Do you want to add other view outside the screen given in the preview?

Comment: Yes. I want do this action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the xml of the view that you want to Put it out of the screen. For example to put it outside the right bound. Simply add

```
    android:layout_marginRight="-250dp"
```